# Data not Coming correctly from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I try to make student result management system. I face problem when I try to give position every student depend on their total obtain mark in exam. In my output I get 1st(obtain mark 450),2nd(obtain mark 449),4th(obtain mark 448). 3rd position is missing. 5th,10th and also other some position is missing. But I don't find any problem in my code.

My Database

[image]

```
if (!function_exists('get_position_in_exam')) {

function get_position_in_exam($school_id, $exam_id, $class_id, $section_id, $mark) {


    $ci = & get_instance();
    $sql = "SELECT id, total_obtain_mark, FIND_IN_SET( total_obtain_mark,(
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( total_obtain_mark  ORDER BY total_obtain_mark DESC ) 
            FROM exam_results WHERE school_id = $school_id AND exam_id = $exam_id AND class_id = $class_id AND section_id = $section_id ))
            AS rank 
            FROM exam_results
            WHERE school_id = $school_id AND exam_id = $exam_id AND class_id = $class_id AND section_id = $section_id AND total_obtain_mark = $mark"; 

    $rank =  @$ci->db->query($sql)->row()->rank; 

    if($mark == 0){
        return '--'; 
    }

    if($rank == 1){
        return $rank.'st';
    }elseif($rank == 2){
       return $rank.'nd'; 
    }elseif($rank == 3){
       return $rank.'rd'; 
    }elseif($rank > 3 ){
        return $rank.'th';         
    }else{
        return '--'; 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: do you have duplicate exam results for the cases around missing ranks?

Comment: yes , how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  distinct total_obtain_mark  in your subquery

`GROUP_CONCAT( distinct total_obtain_mark  ORDER BY total_obtain_mark DESC )`

```
"SELECT id, total_obtain_mark, FIND_IN_SET( total_obtain_mark,(
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( distinct total_obtain_mark  ORDER BY total_obtain_mark DESC ) 
   FROM exam_results WHERE school_id = $school_id AND exam_id = $exam_id AND class_id = $class_id AND section_id = $section_id ))
   AS rank 
   FROM exam_results
   WHERE school_id = $school_id AND exam_id = $exam_id AND class_id = $class_id AND section_id = $section_id AND total_obtain_mark = $mark";
```

otherwise if you have some student with same rank you skip position